# Cannot always get reflect info for func signature in Go

Tags: go, reflection

I have this which returns a string representation of a function signature:

```
func getFuncSignature(v interface{}) string {

    funcValue := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    funcType := funcValue.Type()
    name := funcType.Name()

    // Function signature
    var params []string
    for i := 0; i < funcType.NumIn(); i++ {
        nm := funcType.In(i).Name()
        if strings.TrimSpace(nm) == "" {
            nm = "<unk>"    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE 1
        }
        params = append(params, nm)
    }

    var returns []string
    for i := 0; i < funcType.NumOut(); i++ {
        nm := funcType.Out(i).Name()
        if strings.TrimSpace(nm) == "" {
            nm = "<unk>"  // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE 2
        }
        returns = append(returns, nm)
    }

    paramsStr := strings.Join(params, ", ")
    returnsStr := strings.Join(returns, ", ")

    if name != "" {
        return fmt.Sprintf("(func %s(%s) => (%s))", name, paramsStr, returnsStr)
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("(func(%s) => (%s))", paramsStr, returnsStr)
}
```

however, some parameter and return types return empty strings, so I put in "" which isn't really ideal. Is there some way to retrieve the names/types of the input and return values?

Answer (score 4):

The [Type.Name()](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type.Name) method returns the type's name.  Not all types have a name. For example, the type `[]byte` has no name.

Use [Type.String()](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Type.String) to get a string representation of any type.

```
var params []string
for i := 0; i < funcType.NumIn(); i++ {
    params = append(params, funcType.In(i).String())
}

var returns []string
for i := 0; i < funcType.NumOut(); i++ {
    returns = append(returns, funcType.Out(i).String())
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/4ypAlnQN-tX

You can also call `String()` on the function type.  The `String()` method returns a different result from the code in the question, but it may meet your requirements.

```
func getFuncSignature(v interface{}) string {
    return reflect.Typeof(v).String()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/8E4E76T9lfr

Comment: nice this helps, thanks